# Cannot pull videos from youtube uploads

Tags: c#, youtube-api

Can someone enlighten me as to why I cannot pull the user upload videos from a channel?  I don't know what else I could be missing in my code, everything seems to be there but I always get back a zero on my playlistresponse.items.

```
    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { ApiKey = "API-KEY" }); // mypersonal key
    var ChannelSectionRequest = youtubeService.Channels.List("contentDetails");
    ChannelSectionRequest.Id = channelID;
    var ChannelSectionResponse = await ChannelSectionRequest.ExecuteAsync();
    foreach (var ChannelSectionItem in ChannelSectionResponse.Items)
    {
        var uploadsPlaylistID = ChannelSectionItem.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;
        var nextPageToken = "";
        while (nextPageToken != null)
        {
            var playlistRequest = youtubeService.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");
            playlistRequest.Id = uploadsPlaylistID;
            playlistRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            playlistRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;
            var playlistResponse = await playlistRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the [`playlistId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#playlistId) parameter rather than the [`id`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#id) parameter while building `playlistRequest`:

```
playlistRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsPlaylistID;
```

Comment: Man you are a genius.  I have been staring at that code for two days now.

Comment: @sledgehammer I'm glad I could help! :D